# how can I get my 'before' function to make other tests wait for its completion?

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, mocha.js

```
describe 'TheObject', ->
  before ->
    console.log 'loading text'
    fs.readFile('../data/data.json', 'utf8', (err, data) ->
      text = data
    )
  describe 'simple', ->
    it 'should pass a simple test', ->
      b = "1"
      b.should.equal "1"
```

I'd like to make it so that none of my tests run until the file read in the `before` action is complete. But this is asynch world here, so I think it's behaving as expected. Can I put all my other tests into a callback somehow? Can I force the readFile to be blocking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When async, your `before` function should accept a `done` callback parameter that it calls when it's completed its processing:

```
describe 'TheObject', ->
  before (done) ->
    console.log 'loading text'
    fs.readFile('../data/data.json', 'utf8', (err, data) ->
      text = data
      done()
    )
```

Comment: I added the done() to to the readFile call and a test that looks like `  describe 'test data', ->
    it 'should be present', ->
      text.should.not.equal (null)` but it's still failing: text is undefined.